# Reading excel 2007 and writing file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to retrieve file from ftp server, I have also used Apache poi `client.retrieveFile()` method, but I'm unable to open it which is showing:

> excel cannot open  file check file extension and file format. check file is not corrupted

Then I used file reader and writer. Below is my code snippet.

```
public void testFileWriter()
    {
        try{

        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles("/Ftp1");
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            File serverFile = new File("D:/Pondi.xlsx");
            if(!serverFile.isFile())
            {
                serverFile.createNewFile();
            }
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(serverFile));
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            InputStream inputStream = client.retrieveFileStream("/Ftp1/"+ file.getName());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            System.out.println("Created Reader");
            while(reader.read()!=-1)
            {
                String temp = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(temp);


                writer.write(temp);
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        }

        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this crucial issue.

Comment: I am not sure if `reader.readLine()` is a good idea if you want to read binary data...

Comment: I have also used POI method client.retreiveFile(String path,  FileOutputStream); but this also of no use.

Comment: Do you copy the file using Java and **after** copying it you try to open it with excel (not inside your Java program), right?

Comment: Right, i also try to read excel after writing but it is throwing an exception.

Comment: How you open the file?

Comment: @user2335004 could you please edit your question and clarify what you are doing inside your Java program, what your goal is and that you use excel outside you Java program? It seems that this does not stand out clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read and copy binary data, you must not use `reader.readLine()`, because there are no lines in a binary file. Therefore, this attempt will most likely fail.

Copy it like this instead:

```
int fileNo = 0;
for (FTPFile file : files) {
    File serverFile = new File("D:/Pondi_" + fileNo + ".xlsx");
    ...
    InputStream in = client.retrieveFileStream("/Ftp1/"+ file.getName());
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(serverFile);

    // read and copy binary data
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
    fileNo++;
}
```

Beside that, consider giving your files a different name that `D:/Pondi.xlsx`, because otherwise the file gets overridden again and again in the loop. I did this with `fileNo`.

Comment: Problem solved, I have to set the file type to binary in spite default type of ASCII.below is the code snippet: client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an API for working with it. You can't read these files like reading normal text files.

[JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) will be good for your need.

Examples are be available [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html)

For copying files make use of [this](http://www.java-examples.com/copy-binary-file-using-streams). Reading the file for copying by the method that you used won't work properly.

Hope will be helpful for you.

Comment: I also have to write it in my local environment your answer only describe about to read it.

Comment: "Write it in my local environment"?? What you mean by that? If you can read it, can't u use the data for further processing?

Comment: OP tries to copy the file from FTP server to the local computer. After that, the OP tries to open it with Excel, which shows an error.

Comment: @Maximin u haven't seen mess